# Android Remote push notification- Set sound in repeat mode

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am able to play **Remote Push Notification** sound. But sound stops as soon as the sound file placed in raw folder plays completely. 
I want to play sound in repeat mode till there is a user action.

Can't use FLAG_INSISTENT with notification builder as it is a remote notification.

Comment: Playing sound in repeat mode for a notification is not good for UX .. I don't Notification builder support such feature .. you have to play sound with a `MediaPayer` probably in a service and that's too much i guess...

Comment: @ADM This alert is very important for the user like a 'THEFT ALERT'.
I cannot play MediaPlayer as when application is killed, onMessageReceived() is not called on many devices and hence the alert is missed.

Comment: [notification messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background) will be deliver to `#onMessageReceived()` .. There are two types of messages in FCM notification and data .. You should use `notification messages` . and start a service to play the sound .

Comment: We can start a service when we receive FCM inside app but  **notification messages** are directly rendered in notification panel.  #onMessageReceived() is not called in this case.