# Android full screen notification when application is in the background

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, fullscreen, android-push-notification

I want to apply full notification like Whatsapp incoming call to our phone. But I can't do that when my android apps is in the background state.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
minSdk 23
targetSdk 32
```

I have tried to use `Broadcast Receiver` and `Foreground Service` but it only works when application is on the foreground state.

Thank you

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on time-sensitive notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive)?

Comment: Yes I do, but I only shows Heads Up notification, what I want is a full screen notification like Whatsapp incoming call

Comment: so your issue is unable to receive notification in background state? from which platform you are sending the notification?

Comment: Yes @Ankit I can't receive notification in my background state, I have tried 2 devices those are with API 29 and API 27

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083727/7248394 check this.

Comment: Owh I just realized that I use "notification" type payload to send the push notification where it means the System Tray will receive that notification. I will try to change it into "data" type. I'll inform you the result. Thanks for the information @Ankit

Comment: Thank you, now my Firebase can receive notification in background state

Comment: Try to change your ```firebase_messaging```  to latest version and this follow the implementation.