# Why Firebase push notification work only when App is closed

Tags: firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I don't receive any notification when my application is open. Is this normal? I just receive push notifications when my app is closed.
My service is:

```
<service
     android:name=".FirebaseNotificationService"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I guess you are sending the notification from Firebase console, if it the case then yes. it's normal. 
check this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: if you want your app to receive notification on both way you have to send notification data from your server or serverless function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended. Messages received when in foreground will be handled in `onMessageReceived()`. Similar post answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37395785/20447561).