# How to send extras on BroadCastReceiver class using PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I need your help! When I put extras in my Intent and then I use that Intent to create a Pending Intent it doesn't work! I don't enter to the BroadCastReceiver class.

```
public class Recordatori_Visita extends Activity {
    public void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        Intent intent = new Intent (Recordatori_Visita.this, Receiver.class);
        Long targetCal2 = targetCal.getTimeInMillis();  
        intent.putExtra("targetCal",targetCal2);
        intent.putExtra("n",n);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Recordatori_Visita.this, 1, intent, intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        Bundle bolsaR = k2.getExtras();
        Long extras = bolsaR.getLong("targetCalKey");
        int n= bolsaR.getInt("n");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) k1.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        ...
        notificationManager.notify(1,myNotification);

   }
}
```

I've cut the code, all the variables used are created, I can't find the solution. If I don't put extra data in the intent it works fine but when I putExtra it doesn't work because there is no notification. Thanks!!

Comment: Check it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127957/why-the-pendingintent-doesnt-send-back-my-custom-extras-setup-for-the-intent

Comment: Probably not an answer to your question, but the parameter `intent.FILL_IN_DATA` on the call to `getBroadcast()` is totally wrong. That parameter is for `PendingIntent` flags. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Are you saying that `onReceive()` is not called if you have extras in the `Intent`? Are you sure? Have you added logging in `onReceive()`?

Answer (score 0):

try putting the System time as the `requestCode` in the `getBroadcast()` function.

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Recordatori_Visita.this, requestID, intent, intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```