# Passing extras from widget in PendingIntent to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I can't find a way to pass extras from widget to `Activity` properly.

I wan't to open activity on button click with some extras passed.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateOperationsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("someKey", true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Constants.RequestCodes.CREATE_OPERATIONS, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.add_expense_button, pendingIntent);
```

Activity is opened, but there is no extra in the `Intent`.

The only way I was able to pass that extra was seting `PendingIntent` flag to `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` but then widget button works only wonce, clicking it further takes no action.

How to do that so the extra is intercepted by `Activity` and the button works each time?

Comment: I suffering form same problem but i  put that values in shared storage and get these values form activity  not bcz here we cant put extra in intents

Comment: Ye, I know I can do that, but this just grind my gears... I wan't to do it properly

Comment: me also stuck at that point and dnt get proper answer

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing `setAction()` for your Intent ;) See this one for a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128271/515423

Comment: It doesn't help, but the action is passed properly, contrary to extras ... so it is possible to make workaround using action. Its not clean however