# Pass additional data/bundle to a RemoteInput intent on Wear OS

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os, remote-input

I'm asking for text input on Wear OS using the RemoteInput intent, with the following code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private static final int MESSAGE_INPUT_RESULT = 102;
    private static final String RESULT_KEY = "input_result";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Prepare the input request
                Intent remoteInputIntent = new Intent("android.support.wearable.input.action.REMOTE_INPUT");
                RemoteInput[] remoteInputArray = new RemoteInput[1];
                remoteInputArray[0] = new RemoteInput.Builder(RESULT_KEY)
                        .setAllowFreeFormInput(true)
                        .setLabel("Your message to Bob")
                        .setChoices(new CharSequence[] {"OK", "Thanks"})
                        .build();

                // TODO: this DOESN'T WORK, I need to pass an additional value
                int myValue = 55;
                remoteInputIntent.putExtra("myValue", myValue);
                // TODO:

                // Display the input request
                remoteInputIntent.putExtra("android.support.wearable.input.extra.REMOTE_INPUTS", remoteInputArray);
                startActivityForResult(remoteInputIntent, MESSAGE_INPUT_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MESSAGE_INPUT_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(data);
            if (bundle != null) {
                // TODO: NONE of the two statements below work!
                int myValue = data.getIntExtra("myValue", 0);
                //int myValue = bundle.getInt("myValue");

                // Get the text the user typed
                CharSequence charSequence = bundle.getCharSequence(RESULT_KEY);
                if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0)
                    // Display the text and the value in a toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, charSequence + ", myValue = " + String.valueOf(myValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the toast that is displayed, `myValue` is always `0`. How can I pass additional data using the same intent, so that I will be able to read it in the `onActivityResult` routine and take appropriate actions?

Comment: I think same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859831/startactivityforresult-and-intents-extras-it-seems-extras-are-not-pushed-back . Which suggests this is not supported.