Sending extras with image picking intent from adapter to fragment (Android Kotlin)
I am trying to send position of item from adapter to fragment, with the image picker intent, and trying to receive the value in fragment activity.
But the value is not receiving in the fragment.
The log from adapter is printing the accurate position of itme clicked, but the log from fragment is printing -1 value for position that is efault value that i set in case of null/empty.
This the code for my adapter:
interface ImageSelectionListener {
    fun onImageSelected(position: Int)
}

class FeaturedImageAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val featuredImages: MutableList<FeaturedImageDetails>,
    private val imagePickerLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>,
    private val uploadImageCallback: (Int, Uri) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturedImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var imageSelectionListener: ImageSelectionListener? = null

    fun setImageSelectionListener(listener: ImageSelectionListener) {
        this.imageSelectionListener = listener
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivPickedImage: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPickedImage)
        val tilTitle: TextInputLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tilTitle)
        val tilDescription: TextInputLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tilDescription)
        val btnCancel: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1)


        init {
            ivPickedImage.setOnClickListener {
                val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                imageSelectionListener?.onImageSelected(position)
                Log.d("adapter", "image picker click: $position")
            }


            btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition
                featuredImages[position] = FeaturedImageDetails()
                notifyItemChanged(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_picked_image_in_edit_profile, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val featuredImage = featuredImages[position]

        holder.ivPickedImage.setImageURI(null)
        if (!featuredImage.imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(featuredImage.imageUrl)
                .into(holder.ivPickedImage)
        } else {
            holder.ivPickedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_placeholder)
        }

        holder.tilTitle.editText?.setText(featuredImage.title)
        holder.tilDescription.editText?.setText(featuredImage.detail)

        holder.tilTitle.editText?.doAfterTextChanged {
            featuredImages[position].title = it.toString()
        }

        holder.tilDescription.editText?.doAfterTextChanged {
            featuredImages[position].detail = it.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return featuredImages.size
    }

    fun updateImageUrl(position: Int, imageUrl: String) {
        if (position in featuredImages.indices) {
            featuredImages[position].imageUrl = imageUrl
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }
}

This is my fragment code:

class SocialLinkFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_social_link) {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSocialLinkBinding
    private val featuredImages = MutableList(4) { FeaturedImageDetails() }
    private lateinit var featuredImagesAdapter: FeaturedImageAdapter
 private val imagePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
            val imageUri = result.data!!.data
            val extraPosition = result.data!!.getIntExtra("position", -1)
            Log.d(TAG, "launcher: $extraPosition")
            if (extraPosition != -1 && imageUri != null) {
                uploadImageToFirebase(imageUri) { downloadUrl ->
                    featuredImages[extraPosition].imageUrl = downloadUrl
                    featuredImagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(extraPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object{
        val TAG = "SocialLinkFragment"
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentSocialLinkBinding.bind(view)

        binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }

        binding.rvFeaturedImages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        featuredImagesAdapter = FeaturedImageAdapter(requireContext(), featuredImages, imagePickerLauncher) { position, imageUri ->
            uploadImageToFirebase(imageUri) { downloadUrl ->
                featuredImages[position].imageUrl = downloadUrl
                featuredImagesAdapter.updateImageUrl(position, downloadUrl)
            }
        }
        binding.rvFeaturedImages.adapter = featuredImagesAdapter

        featuredImagesAdapter.setImageSelectionListener(object : ImageSelectionListener {
            override fun onImageSelected(position: Int) {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.putExtra("position", position)
                imagePickerLauncher.launch(intent)
            }
        })



        binding.btnSaveImages.setOnClickListener {
            saveFeaturedImagesToDatabase()
        }

    }}

I need item's position in my screen to load the respective image, and send the image on that position to firebase.

Are you getting the right position in the onImageSelected callback?

Yes, position log.d from adapter is printing correctly. It's not receiving properly as extra in fragment.

Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859831/startactivityforresult-and-intents-extras-it-seems-extras-are-not-pushed-back You cannot pass "extras" to Android using ACTION_PICK and expect that these "extras" come back in the Intent that the PICK action returns. It doesn't work that way.
